# Error al aumentar el valor de la viable Php /sql

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Buen dia, 
desde un formulario php estoy capturando la información en phpmyadmin.

En el fondo esta la realización de una compra que al guardarse en la base de datos va aumentando el numero de compra (compra 1, 2, 3 etc).

He revisado varias veces el código y no he logrado encontrar el error que hace que cada que realizo una compra se guarde con el mismo numero. Es decir, **cada compra que realizo se guarda con el mismo numero de compra en lugar de que el numero de compra vaya aumentando**.

Agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

```
  <?php
session_start();
include "verbindung.php";
$arreglo=$_SESSION['car'];
$numeroventa=0;


$re=mysqli_query($verbindung,"select * from bestellposition order by verkauf_num DESC limit 1") or die(mysqli_error($verbindung));
while ( $f=mysqli_fetch_array($re)) {
  $numeroventa=$f['Verkauf_num'];
  $datum=$f['Datum'];
}

if($numeroventa==0){
  $numeroventa=1;
}else{
  $numeroventa=$numeroventa+1;

}
for($i=0; $i<count($arreglo); $i++){
  mysqli_query($verbindung,"insert into bestellposition (verkauf_num,Kunde_ID,Produkt_ID,Menge,name,Summe) values(
    ".$numeroventa.",
    '".$_SESSION['Kunde_ID']."',
    '".$arreglo[$i]['produkt_id']."',
    '".$arreglo[$i]['menge']."',
    '".$arreglo[$i]['name']."',
    '".($arreglo[$i]['preis']*$arreglo[$i]['menge'])."'
    )")or die(mysqli_error($verbindung));
  }

  for($i=0; $i<count($arreglo);$i++){
    mysqli_query($verbindung,"insert into rechnung (bestellposition_ID,Bestellung_Datum) values(
      ".$numeroventa.",
      '".$datum."'
      )")or die(mysqli_error($verbindung));
    }


  unset($_SESSION['car']);
  header("Location: resume_einkauf.php");

  ?>
```

Comment: No se si sera esto a lo que te refieres pero dentro de los for $numeroventa no se aumenta.

Answer (score 2):

Buenas,

Consultando la documentación oficial del método [mysqli_fecth_array](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp).

> Definition and Usage The mysqli_fetch_array() function fetches a
>   result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both.
>
> Note: Fieldnames returned from this function **are case-sensitive**.

En tu código fuente:

```
$re=mysqli_query($verbindung,"select * from bestellposition order by verkauf_num DESC limit 1") or die(mysqli_error($verbindung));
while ( $f=mysqli_fetch_array($re)) {
  $numeroventa=$f['Verkauf_num']; 
  $datum=$f['Datum'];
}
```

Estas obteniendo el campo `$numeroventa=$f['Verkauf_num'];` con la V en mayúsculas, cuando en todas las sentencias lo usas en minúsculas.

Consulta como MySQL te está devolviendo dicho campo y escribelo tal y como MySQL te lo envíe.

COMENTARIO: Esto en cuanto a lo que te puede estar pasando, sin embargo, estoy de acuerdo con la respuesta de G3l0 en cuanto a que el uso correcto sería utilizar un autoincremental.

Comment: Gracias por tu observación David, ya lo corregí.

Esta fue mi respuesta al compañero G3l0:
Gracias por tu respuesta, si lo pongo como autoincremental, cada vez que realice una compra se guardara con un numero de venta diferente aun cuando sea el mismo cliente y lo que yo necesito es que todas las compras realizadas por el cliente durante una SESSION se guarden con un solo numero de compra.

Answer (score 1):

En la propia base de datos, pon la columna en cuestión como autoincremental, y al pasarle datos si le pasas `null` debería coger el siguiente elemento que le tocase en la secuencia.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, si lo pongo como autoincremental, cada vez que realice una compra se guardara con un numero de venta diferente aun cuando sea el mismo cliente y lo que yo necesito es que todas las compras realizadas por el cliente durante una SESSION se guarden con un solo numero de compra.

Answer (score 0):

Quiero indicarte varias cosas con respecto al código, en el orden en que voy viendo:

1. `SELECT * ...`: **mala práctica a nivel de optimización**, selecciona **solo** las columnas que necesites, no **todas** las columnas de la tabla.
2. `verkauf_num` o `Verkauf_num` ¿Cómo se llama la columna de la tabla **realmente**?
3. `select * from bestellposition order by verkauf_num DESC limit 1` si lo usas **sólo** para saber el último `verkauf_num`, te puedes ahorrar esa consulta declarando la columna `verkauf_num` como **autoincremental** y asignando `NULL` o no indicando nada para esa columna al momento de insertar. De ese modo, **tampoco** tendrías que ejecutar este fragmento de código: `if($numeroventa==0){ ...`, creo que no es la forma más óptima de hacerlo. Además, si hay un fallo en el código podrías tener la variable `$numeroventa` aumentada de forma **irreal**. Da la impresión de que quieres hacer un autoincremental *hand made* (hecho a mano). ¿Por qué no dejas al sistema de base de datos que lo haga y lo gestione él?
4. En el primer `while`, ¿esto `$datum=$f['Datum'];` sirve para algo?
5. Las dos inserciones en sendos bucles `for ...`. Tienen dos problemas. Uno es **gravísimo**, ya que pone en serio riesgo los datos porque dichas consultas son vulnerables a la Inyección SQL. En ese sentido, ver: [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967) El otro es un con respecto al **rendimiento**. Sería mejor construir las inserciones **dentro** del bucle y luego ejecutarlas **en una sola llamada a la base de datos fuera del bucle**. Esto es extremadamente fácil y mucho más seguro cuando se usan consultas preparadas.

*Nota*:

Esto no resuelve tu problema *puntual*, pero revisando el código vi al menos esos cinco fallos y quise señalarlos, porque, aunque resuelvas tu problema *ahora*, te van a dar muchos dolores de cabeza *en el futuro*. Creo que deberías mejorar esos puntos y quizá replantear la forma en que tienes organizada tu base de datos.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario @A. Cedano . Como seguro ya lo haz notado soy nuevo en esto de la programación. Revisare detalladamente los puntos que mencionas y también si las tablas están correctamente normalizadas. Saludos

Comment: No hay de qué. Me lo supuse y por eso quise darte esas indicaciones que podrían ayudarte a empezar con buen pie. Al principio hay cosas que parecen complicadas, pero si empiezas aplicando buenas prácticas en relativamente poco tiempo estarás escribiendo código optimizado y seguro. Saludos.